# What does *mono / もの* mean in the sentence below?

Tags: meaning

わたしから隠れられるものか。
watashi kara kakurerareru mono ka.
You can’t hide from me.

The site that had it displayed it that way. But I don't see the *not being able to hide* part in it. So the word もの must contain some clue to understand it. And because the kanji isn't provided, it is difficult to pinpoint the meaning from the dictionary as too many words show up with もの in it.

Comment: http://jisho.org/search/%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is the right literal translation that reflects the nuance, but it helped me memorize how to use ものか.

"Do you think I am someone from whom you can hide?!"

"Am I someone from whom you can hide?!"

Answer (score 3):

ものか (more politely ものですか, more informally もんか) at the end of a sentence is a way of rejecting the assertion made by the sentence with indignation or contempt. For example:

- 行きません or 行かない means  "I'm not going", "I shan't go"
- 行くものか or 行くもんか means "You won't catch me going", "You don't think I'd go, do you?"
- 彼などに負けない means "I won't be beaten by someone like him"
- 彼などに負けるもんか means "Do you think I'd let somebody like that so-and-so beat me?"

So I'd translate the sentence in question as "You don't think you can hide from me, do you?" or "Think you can hide from me? Fat chance!"